# Image of a open interval of $\mathbb{R}$ under a continuous injection.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f:\left(a;b\right) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous injective function.
Show that $Imf$ is an open interval $\left(c;d\right)$ (can be $\left(-\infty;+\infty\right)$).

I can see, with $f$ be an injective, exist an bijection from $\left(a;b\right)$ to $Im f$. Does an bijection always maps an open set to an open set?

If it correct, i can use the properties of continuous function of connected set to complete. If it not, is there some way to prove it? Thank you for help.

Comment: In general, bijections do not need to map open sets to open sets. There exists a bijection from $[0,1]$ to $(0,1)$ for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set $f\bigl((a,b)\bigr)$ is an interval, by the intermediate value theorem.

Now, suppose that $f\bigl((a,b)\bigr)$ is an interval of the type $[c,d)$ or of the type $[c,d]$. The is some $x_0\in(a,b)$ such that $f(x_0)=c$. Take $x_1,x_2\in(a,b)$ such that $x_1<x_0<x_2$. The, since $f$ is injective and $c$ is the smallest element of $f\bigl((a,b)\bigr)$, $f(x_1),f(x_2)>c$. Suppose that $c<f(x_2)\leqslant f(x_1)$. Then, by the intermediate value theorem, there is some $y\in[x_1,x_0]$ such that $f(y)=f(x_2)$, which is impossible, since $f$ is injective and $y<x_2$. You also reach a contradiction if $c<f(x_1)\leqslant f(x_2)$. So, $f\bigl((a,b)\bigr)$ is *not* an interval of the type $[c,d)$ or of the type $[c,d]$. By the same argument, it is not an interval of the type $(c,d]$ or of the type $[c,d]$.

So, it is an interval of the type $(c,d)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is injective, $f$ is monotonic. We can assume that $f$ is increasing.

Then the limit $L:=\lim_{x\to b} f(x)$ exists in $\mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}.$

And also the limit $l:=\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists in $\mathbb R \cup \{-\infty\}.$

Now invoke the immediate value theorem to see that $Im f=(l,L).$